# Deleting the last even number in a number list

Tags: python

```py
# Task_5
def delete_last_even(num_list):
    """Removes the last even number from a list of numbers.
    Args:
        num_list (list): List of numbers to be checked.
    Returns:
        list: List of numbers with the last even number
            removed.
    """
    if len(num_list) % 2 == 0:
        num_list.pop()
    else:
        return num_list

delete_last_even([7, 65, 1337, 8, -2, 24, 6, 67, 54, 36, 25, 1, 42, 9, 138, 4356, 6])
```

Let me know what I am interpreting wrong. My if statement is asking if a number in variable (num_list) is even, then invoke the .pop() function to remove the last item from the list. Finally, return num_list. When I run this I get, None.

Comment: You get `None` as the `return` statement only executes if the length of the list is an odd value.  Additionally; this is *not* removing the ‘last even value’, it’s removing the last value. Yes, the logic is wrong and should be redesigned.  Tip: How would you work this out on paper?  Then, implement that.

Comment: you can start from the last element and check if even then pop() if not keep looping over the list

Comment: This is not working because `list.pop()` will return `None`. Placing `return num_list` outside of the `else` branch will just fix the code. Note that the wording here implies that you are looking for numbers inside the list and will remove the last even number occurring inside the list. However, the code is doing something very different: if the list contains an even number of elements (which could all be odd, or not even be number) it is removing the last element (regardless of its content).

Answer (score 2):

First you have to find the index of the last even character. For that you can enumerate the reversed list `num_list[::-1]`. Then you have to pop it from the list and you can either return the list or print the updated list as below.
Note that here we are enumerating in order to find the index of the even letter inside the list.

```
def delete_last_even(num_list):
    for index, number in enumerate(num_list[::-1]):
        if number % 2 == 0 :
            num_list.pop(len(num_list)-1-index)
            return num_list
    return num_list
```

You can check the output for your test case as shown below

```
print(delete_last_even([7, 65, 1337, 8, -2, 24, 6, 67, 54, 36, 25, 1, 42, 9, 138, 4356, 6]))
```

If you want to know more about enumerate function you can refer [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have misread the requirement, it asks you to remove `last even number`, but you've checked the `len` of the list.  And the earlier PO in comments have answered your why `None` return question already.

Here is just one another way to approach it, and also compare the performance with other PO to show the difference.

```
def delete_last_even(nums):
    for i, num in enumerate(reversed(nums)):  # to reverse the contents of a list object in-place.  You won't be creating a new list. 
        if num % 2 == 0:
            nums.pop(~i)     # directly remove the num by ~i, aka, backward idx
            
            break

    return nums
```

Output:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
delete_last_even(A) 
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
delete_last_even([6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
#  [6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]            *
```

##### Performance comparison: `first function is 51% faster than 2nd one.`.

If the input size is significant, it may be a legit concern.

```
In [1]: nums = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 21]

In [2]: def delete_last_even(nums):
   ...:     # same as theabove code
   ...:

In [3]: def delete_last_even2(nums):
   ...:     for idx, n in enumerate(nums[::-1]):
   ...:         if n % 2 == 0:
   ...:             nums.pop(idx)
   ...:             break
   ...:     return nums
   ...:

In [4]: %timeit delete_last_even(nums)
761 ns ± 54.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit delete_last_even2(nums)
1.2 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a questionable approach. (1) it works only incidentally, as `list.remove()` will remove the first appearance of its first argument, so, for example: `[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` passed to your function will produce `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. (2) It is modifying a list while the list is being iterated over, and this may lead to unpredictable results in the general case. (3) the benchmarks are not very informative as their relative performance is likely to depend on the input size as well as being dependent on the input itself.

Comment: @norok2 Thanks for the good catch. Correct it and re-post it.

Comment: You forgot the `~` in `delete_last_even2`.

Comment: Got it.  Just update the first function.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when the length is divisible by 2, you have no objects you are returning.

Additionally, what you have is removing the last element of the list if the length is even. From your task request it isn't clear to me that's what you want, as "remove last even number" could also mean find the last even element and remove it. So [0,1,2] would map to [0,1], [2,1,3] would map to [1,3] and [3,1] would just map to itself if you are wanting to find the last even element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for index,num in enumerate(num_list[::-1]) :
    if num%2==0:
        num_list.pop(len(num_list)-1-index)
        break

return num_list
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?  Just posting some code is (generally) not helpful to the individual asking the question. Help them understand *why* it’s an effective answer.

Comment: That's right, I did not see the elaborate.

Comment: Please review [@Sangeerththan Balachandran's virtually identical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329833/3025856) , submitted a bit after your own, for a good example of the level of detail we expect on Stack Overflow. As their answer came in after your own, it's even possible that they simply expanded on your code with a proper explanation—though I wouldn't assume so. Regardless, their post has a couple of upvotes already as it's much more useful to offer an explanation instead of simply offering a block of code.